# Find out which form shares questions

Tags: r, excel, tableau-api, data-cleaning

I have a data set like this .

```
NA.       CODE                ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION COLLEGE_CODE TOTAL_ITEMS SHARED_ITEMS
 1   4020.1.2-01.8x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 2   4020.1.3-02.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 3   4020.1.1-06.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 4   4020.1.3-02.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 5   4020.1.3-04.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 6   4020.1.2-06.5x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 7   4020.1.5-07.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 8   4020.1.1-04.5x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
 9   4020.1.2-01.8x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
10   4020.1.3-02.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
11   4020.1.1-06.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
12   4020.1.3-02.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
13   4020.1.3-04.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
```

What i want to do is find out  what other forms share questions with each form. 
For example ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION AA01.4.A shared a few questions with AAO1.4.B. I want  to see that for every form. I also would like to know how many question a form shares with another form. from the example above  AAO1.4.A shares 5 questions with AAO1.4.B . So i want something like

```
  NA   ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION   SHARED       Number of Shared codes                     
     1   AAO1.4.A               AAO1.4.B       5
```

---

Comment: is `NA.` the columns with the questions? If so should the first number (the one that matches the first column) be ignored?

Comment: No. NA. is the number  before code. Code is the column with questions. Sorry for the confusion.  I will do better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to self-join your data set and filter it to cases where form names on the left are less than form names on the right (for example).

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- read.table(text = 
"row                CODE ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION COLLEGE_CODE TOTAL_ITEMS SHARED_ITEMS
1    1 4020.1.2-01.8x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
2    2 4020.1.3-02.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
3    3 4020.1.1-06.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
4    4 4020.1.3-02.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
5    5 4020.1.3-04.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
6    6 4020.1.2-06.5x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
7    7 4020.1.5-07.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
8    8 4020.1.1-04.5x.A.V1                AAO1.4.A           IT          45            8
9    9 4020.1.2-01.8x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
10  10 4020.1.3-02.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
11  11 4020.1.1-06.1x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
12  12 4020.1.3-02.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8
13  13 4020.1.3-04.2x.A.V1                AAO1.4.B           IT          49            8  
", stringsAsFactors = F)

questions <- data.table(dt)

question.matches <- merge(questions, questions, by = "CODE")

question.matches <- question.matches[ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x < ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.y]
question.matches[, .(matches = .N), .(ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x, ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.y)]

 #   ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.y matches
 # 1:                  AAO1.4.A                  AAO1.4.B       5
```

Comment: the data is to big to read in like that. there are 20k rows. Is there a different way to make the data table? Thank you

Comment: depends on the source, if it is csv, `data.table` has `fread` function

Comment: It is an excel file.  .xlsx. So , do i just read the data in again  using read.xlsx with another name and continue accordingly with the next steps?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for everything.  I'm getting this error.                   
      question.matches <- question.matches[ ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x < ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.y]
Error in `[.data.frame`(question.matches, ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x <  : 
  object 'ASSESSMENT_FORM_VERSION.x' not found  .                                      When i try to put double quotes i for assessment_for_version.x and .y , the code is running but nothing is happening

Comment: did you install `data.table` package? eg. `library(data.table)` should be run